# Purchasing foreign ebooks on kindle

Tags: kindle

Reading german books on the kindle. As I based in the UK and would like to read more german books and take advantage of kindle offers on the german kindle store. Can we have both the UK and German kindle at same time? Or how to purchase German titles ?

Anyone with any advice?